# What does the phrase "connected to the idea of using" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence from a game's description:

"This studio had experience filming miniatures for television, and this game’s wistful settings connected to the idea of using real-world scale models. "

The game uses both 3D technique and handmade photos. To make the visuals more attractive, developers have used real-scale models. I am not sure about the meaning of the phrase "connected to the idea of using" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using "connected" as the past tense of the verb "to connect" meaning "made a connection" or in this case "became associated with". Since the passive voice was used, we aren't actually told who made the connection or where it occurred. I suspect the true meaning is that the connection was  "in the minds of the game developers",  but that probably didn't sound good to the marketing people. A less jargony way of saying this might hav been

> ...this game’s wistful settings seemed to work well with idea of using real-world scale models.

or perhaps

> ... this game’s wistful settings suggested to our staff the idea of using real-world scale models.

Those are clearer and quite likely more accurate, but perhaps they wouldn't sell the game as well.